# I'm looking for resources to understand the fundamentals of delta-epsilon proofs

Tags: reference-request, proof-writing, soft-question, epsilon-delta

Here are some examples of proofs I struggle with:

1. Consider the sequence {$15^2+2√+3$} $\lim\limits_{→∞} 15^2+2√+3$=_____
2. Let $()=2^2−4+5$. Use the − definition to prove that $\lim\limits_{ \to  -1} 2^2−4+5≠8$.

I'm struggling with how to solve these proofs in general, my textbook hasn't been great.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1745550/logic-behind-epsilon-delta-proofs-single-variable-calculus?rq=1

Comment: You are allowed to cheat to get inspiration. For 2) we know $2x^2-4x +5$ is continuous so we know that $\lim_{x\to -1} 2x^2-4x + 5$ *is* actually $2(-1)^2 -4(-1) +5=11\ne 8$.  So we know as $x$ gets close to $-1$, $f(x)$ *doesn't* get close to $8$.   So show that for some $\epsilon$ there is a $\delta$ small enough that $-1-\delta<x< -1+\delta$ then $f(x) > 8 + \epsilon$.  This shouldn't be hard as if $\delta$ is small enough $f(x)\approx 11$.  If say $\delta=\frac 14$ for and $\epsilon=1$ then for $-1.25<x<-0.75$ we have $f(x) > 9 =8+1 > 8+\epsilon$. That proves the limit is not $8$.

Comment: It should be intuitively obvious that as $n\to \infty$ that $15n^2\to \infty$ and $\sqrt n\to \infty$ so $\lim_{n\to \infty} 15n^2+ \sqrt n + 3=\infty$.  The proof needs to show that for any $K$ no matter how big there is an $N$ so that for all $n > N$ we have $15n^2 + \sqrt n + 3 > K$.  Well, there's no bonus being *close*.  If $n > N> 1$ and $N \ge K$ then $15n^2 + \sqrt n + 3 > 15n^2 > n^2 > n > N \ge K$ and that's it we are done.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does there exist an epsilon-delta proof of the limit for all polynomials?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1485468/does-there-exist-an-epsilon-delta-proof-of-the-limit-for-all-polynomials)